# Margin note in wrong place

Tags: marginpar, marginnote

I'm typing a book in Hebrew. The first time I run LaTeX with `\marginpar` everything looks wonderful and is in the correct place. Every time after that, however, the margin text usually finds itself overlapping the body text. It's like each time I run the code the margin text closer towards the center of the page.

Does anybody have any insight? How might I fix this problem?

EDIT: Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{report}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{.5in}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
דת עזה הגולשות פילוסופיה, כלל את היום לכאן, חפש ב שמות באגים פולנית. תרומה המחשב מדינות אחר בה. כדי מועמדים קרימינולוגיה ביוטכנולוגיה מה, היסטוריה אנתרופולוגיה קרן אם. של כימיה רפואה זכר. אנא עזרה מדויקים אווירונאוטיקה דת.
\marginnote{אבגדה}

לוח על ביולוגיה העריכהגירסאות, בקר אם מוגש בדפים הגרפים. צ'ט את יידיש מיזמי אקטואליה. מה כלל תרבות ספורט
\marginnote{אבגדה}
, דת אנא ציור פוליטיקה טכנולוגיה. על כלל תרומה הנדסת. ספורט מושגי היסטוריה שער מה, המחשב בגרסה תבניות מה קרן, אם אחד לכאן למתחילים ביוטכנולוגיה.
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Comment: I'm trying... on my MWE, the opposite happens! The margin note is originally off the page, then on second run it's in the perfect spot!

Comment: `\marginpar`s float, so I'd guess that has something to do with the problem. Hard to say, of course, without a MWE. If you'd rather just try other possibilities, see the [CTAN topic for marginal notes](https://www.ctan.org/topic/marginal). Some document classes, such as `memoir` also have extended facilities for making marginal notes.

Comment: `\marginpar` works, but I get a bunch of float errors (expected). It's `\marginnote` that I'd like to use but isn't.